# How to get all checkbox props with React + ASP.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am learning React and ASP.net( not core).
I try to create a small project for practice.

I have a number of checkboxes and a submit button.
The idea is when I click on the button I want to create a Jason that will contain a list of the checkboxes text and their states (check \uncheck).
That Jason I want to send to the server.

I mange to create the components and the relevant events.
But fail to create the following

1)  Get the state of the checkbox from the submit component and create a Jason out of it.

2)  Send that Jason to the server side (ASP.net).

I try to flow the [tutorial](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html) but didn’t get it, I tried to find solution on the internet but with no lack.

If someone can show me how to do it – or give me some direction that will help

Thanks

the jsk:

```
var data = [
  { Id: 1, ActionItem: "Action1" },
  { Id: 2, ActionItem: "Action2" },
  { Id: 3, ActionItem: "Action3" }
];
var Checkbox = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
   return {
    isChecked: false
   };
 },

 toggleChange: function() {
  this.setState({
   isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
   },
 function() {
   console.log(this.state);
  }.bind(this));
 },
 render: function() {
   return (
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox"
     checked={this.state.isChecked}
     onChange={this.toggleChange} />{this.props.chkboxlabel}<br />
   </label>
  );
 }
});

var ActionBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="actionBox">
        <h1>Select Action </h1>
        <CheckboxList data={this.props.data} />
        <SubmitForm/>
      </div>
   );
  }
});

var CheckboxList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var actionNodes = this.props.data.map(function(action) {
       return (
        <Checkbox chkboxlabel={action.ActionItem} key={action.id}>
          {action.ActionItem}
        </Checkbox>
    );
 });
 return (
    <form className="actionList">{actionNodes}
    </form>
   );
  }
});


var SubmitForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
      //??
},
render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="actionForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="submit" value="Run" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <ActionBox data={data} />,
   document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Can you be more clear? Also, I feel like proper indentation would be allow to read better the code.

Comment: How can I get the state of all the checkbox from the event handleSubmit? (How to loop through all the check boxes components)

Comment: Maybe you should maintain the state for each checkbox in the ActionBox's component state and then pass it down to each checkbox as props. In React, data flows down, so consider maintaining the app state in an outer container component and passing the data down as props to the children components.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works I don’t think it’s the best way but maybe it will help other.
I loop thought the element to get the value- I believe there is a better way  of doing it with react.

```
var data = [
{ Label: "Action 1", IsChecked: false, Name: "a1" },
{ Label: "Action 2", IsChecked: false, Name: "a2" },
{ Label: "Action 3", IsChecked: false, Name: "a3" }

];
handleCommentSubmit: function () {
    var data = new FormData();
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName('mycheckbox');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var name = inputs.item(i).value;
        var ischecked = inputs.item(i).checked;
        data.append(name, ischecked);
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
    xhr.send(data);
},
```